# Grit warnings on ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby, diff, warnings, grit

I'm learning **[grit](https://github.com/mojombo/grit/)** (version 2.4.1). Here is my basic code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -wKU

require "grit"
repo = Grit::Repo.new("./myproject")

p repo.commits
```

Running this code gave me a lot of warnings. [This GitHub diff](https://github.com/mojombo/grit/pull/71/files#diff-0), as pointed out by user @Dogbert, helped me removing some of them and now I get the only the following:

**UPDATE**

changing `hunk = hunk.map { |block| yield block }` into `hunk = hunk.map { |blk| yield block }` both at lines 266 and 303 of [diff-lcs](http://github.com/defunkt/diff-lcs) (v1.1.2) removed this two warnings:

```
/Users/mircospino/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/diff-lcs-1.1.2/lib/diff/lcs.rb:266: warning: shadowing outer local variable - block
/Users/mircospino/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/diff-lcs-1.1.2/lib/diff/lcs.rb:303: warning: shadowing outer local variable - block
```

**UPDATE 2**

As user @injekt says [here](https://github.com/mojombo/grit/issues/76#issuecomment-1409489) process.rb will be removed in the next release. This will get rid of:

```
/Users/mircospino/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/grit-2.4.1/lib/grit/process.rb:289: warning: method redefined; discarding old spawn
/Users/mircospino/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/grit-2.4.1/lib/grit/process.rb:221: warning: previous definition of spawn was here
```

**UPDATE 3**

THX to user @DogBert...

```
/Users/mircospino/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/diff-lcs-1.1.2/lib/diff/lcs/hunk.rb:69: warning: method redefined; discarding old flag_context=
```

...Disappeared by changing line 68 of hunk.rb, from `:attr_accessor` to `:attr_reader` inside the diff-lcs gem

Now I have a **"stackoverflow meta"** question: 
**what I have to do with this question?**

Comment: Are you sure you edited the correct files (the gem in use) by hand? That should've fixed the warnings.

Comment: Yes, I removed "lazy_reader :author_string" from /Users/microspino/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/grit-2.4.1/lib/grit/commit.rb do I have to do something more?

Comment: Yes, this is the complete diff. https://github.com/mojombo/grit/pull/71/files

Comment: If the question is about a subsystem, please link to it, and also consider filling in the tag data as well. (I added the link.)

Comment: updated warnings after following the diff @DogBert pointed out.

Comment: @DigitalRoss I can't create the diff-lcs tag (i'm under 1500) but I added the link to the github project

Comment: @microspino, change line 68 of hunk.rb, `accessor` -> `reader`

Comment: Post your solution as an answer, and accept it. That way it won't be listed in the unanswered listing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to remove the warnings by:

[This GitHub diff,](https://github.com/mojombo/grit/pull/71/files#diff-0) thx to @DogBert

changed `hunk = hunk.map { |block| yield block }` into `hunk = hunk.map { |blk| yield block }` both at lines 266 and 303 of diff-lcs (v1.1.2)

As user @injekt says here `process.rb` will be removed in the next release. This will get rid of this warnings:

```
warning: method redefined; discarding old spawn
warning: previous definition of spawn was here
```

As user @DogBert said changing line 68 of hunk.rb, from `:attr_accessor` to `:attr_reader` inside the **diff-lcs gem** removed `warning: method redefined; discarding old flag_context=...`